# Failed to install six.apk on device 'emulator-5556 Launch canceled

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, emulation, logcat

When I run my android application I faced an installation error which is: failed to install my app on emulator and launch cancelled. My app shows a google map to the user.

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="************************** "
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.six"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.six.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"         
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>    
    </application>   
</manifest>
```

Main file

```
package com.example.six;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;}
        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            return false;

    }


}
```

Please tell me is there any problem with my code or is something wrong with my eclipse?
I have eclipse juno and sdk 4.2 and I am using google api level 17.

Comment: Is your Emulator set to use google APIs?

Comment: yes i have instelled google API'S and select google API while seting up a project

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator image needs to use the Google APIs

Comment: i have already use google API in my project but i dont knw what the reasn behind

Comment: When you create the emulator image that needs to be made with the Google APIs too